# Vuejs - SEO Prerendering

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack, server-side-rendering, prerender

I have created a project using vue-cli and webpack (not webpack basic) and added pre-rendering using prerender-spa-plugin , since my application uses laravel API so i only pre-rendered some of the static pages like about us, contact us and not the login or signup page. so my question is that How will I serve (host) my application? two serves, one for crawler and one for users? or can i do that with the single serve?

NOTE: I dont want to use server side rendering.

Comment: Deploy the site normally. all `html`s generated by `prerender-spa-plugin` contain correct references to your js and css..

when a request comes to your server for say `/about` page, your prerendered `about.html` will be served which has template for your about page and also acts as `index.html` for your app.

if you meant to ask something else, pls let me know.

Comment: sorry i don't  understand .
I created my project using vue-cli 
-> vue webpack init my-app 

----------------------------------------------
I'm confused how to add plugin with the boiler plate code + config 
all solution provide with (basic-webpack code )

@pranavjindal999